# How to tell bosses that they are not working systemically

Tags: work-environment

I've been interning at a startup as a project manager for the last 2 months.

Whenever I make  a mistake and take a wrong step my boss will just randomly drop me message stating that I did not do things correctly.

So I am considering to bring this up and set a meeting the next working day and tell them that I think that it  is not a good practice to drop me a message about my mistake randomly.
Instead we can have a weekly retrospective meeting every Friday to review my work for the week. During this week they can tell me about my good/bad things.

I work remotely and in a small team (9-12 people).

What do you suggest?

Scenario: Last Tuesday, we met and had discussed some tasks for myself that needs to be achieved by end of this week. As a manager, I need to manage Business side and the technological side. So i has some tasks from both the side. Suddenly my boss drops me a message last thursday evening and states that i have been not doing my job correctly.Note: here he did not mention about any task, he just said i am not doing it correctly. Firstly: It was outside my working hours. Secondly: It sounded rude to me.

Now last Friday, my lead of technological side comes and points out some of my mistakes and tell on the call with him. Which i understand. because it was within my working hours. and it was call. So he has more room to explain where i am going wrong and where i am not. Coincidentally, both of them pointed out the same mistakes.

To overcome such situation, I want to tell that i would be great to have scheduled day and time to discuss this stuff.

I totally respect that they want to point out mistakes, but i feel it should be within some "rules" they can't just drop me a message and tell me.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That my bosses(2) they randomly point my mistakes and drop me a message(no call) stating i committed a mistake. I am trying to find a way to over come this inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks. I will update my question with a scenario to better understand.

Comment: I don't see anything "inconsistent" here. You made a mistake, you were told about it. Why is it important that you are told on a Friday?

Comment: Thanks @PhilipKendall I have updated my question. with some more content to visualise the scenario.

Comment: I fail to see the bad thing about being told about an error immediately? It seems to me that this is actually preferable, since the scenario is still fresh in everyone's mind, and corrective action (if needed) can be taken ASAP, rather than continuing down the wrong path. What is the actual problem you're having with this?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think agree if it immediate! this is not immediate. See the scenario. one boss messages me about the mistake, whereas other does tell on a video call. I am actually cool with the call, as there is substance the mistake is JUST committed. Where as the boss who message me on Thursday, it is not related to "thursday" or "wednesday" it like reviewing my whole 1month journey!

Comment: So is your problem *actually* the fact that you are not getting timely feedback from your boss, rather than when the messages are sent? That is reasonable; demanding all feedback be in one meeting on a Friday is not.

Comment: yeap! I just thought of one way to solve this issue of having a review meeting on fridays.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should have a weekly meeting to discuss your project and correct any mistakes that you have been making. I would not tell him to stop dropping you messages. This could come off as disrespectful.

Hopefully once you set up a weekly meeting, the random messages will stop since the manager knows they have a set time to discuss all of these things with you.

Comment: Thanks. Which means i should not point out that randomly-drooping message. Whereas I should tell them that we could have weekly meeting to discuss my progress?